# Getting "The ssl connection could not be established" or "SSL handshake aborted" when trying to log in from android app to my server

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, ssl, xamarin

I have a xamarin project and I'm trying to connect to my server with it. It is an app that uses the same server as a website. I found some workarounds with "The ssl connection could not be established" error and used

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };
```

So when I use this workaround, I receive "The ssl connection could not be established" and when I don't - I receive "SSL handshake aborted".
When I tried to debug the app using fiddler and proxy - there were no errors and connection worked fine. I use HttpClient for connections

**EDIT 1**
I am using self signed certificate

Comment: Are you using a self-signed cert?

Comment: @SushiHangover yes, I do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out, that you can not connect to your network using emulated device 
[without proxy](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

> "An emulated device can't see your development machine or other emulator instances on the network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet to a router/firewall."